How to Avoid Page Filckering on textbox postback ? in Asp.Net We are using c#
having multiple textbox with AutoPostBack = true and having Poastback methods to calculate
now every textbox pasting back on page and reload the Whole page
we are using Update panel too.
Please assist how to prevent this reload or flicker on poastback.
thank you very much
I Trid to update the update panel on every postback but its not working.\

You can share the code, It should only update contents in the defined in the UpdatePanel if whole page is refreshing then you may be doing something wrong.. You need to share the code so we can understand what is happening

First, it would help the readers here boatloads if you provided some sample markup.
As a general rule, a text box placed in a update panel should not cause a full page post-back. Make sure you using a asp.net text box for this.
So, say this markup:
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div style="padding:35px">

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>

                <div style="float: left">
                    First Name:
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirst" runat="server"
                    OnTextChanged="txtFirst_TextChanged"
                    AutoPostBack="true">
                </asp:TextBox>
                </div>

                <div style="float: left; margin-left: 20px">
                    First Name:
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLast" runat="server"
                    OnTextChanged="txtLast_TextChanged"
                    AutoPostBack="true">
                </asp:TextBox>
                </div>

                <div style="clear:both"></div>

                <h3>Result</h3>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtResult" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>


            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

And then code behind:
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void txtFirst_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtResult.Text = $"{txtFirst.Text} {txtLast.Text}";
    }

    protected void txtLast_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        txtResult.Text = $"{txtFirst.Text} {txtLast.Text}";
    }

So, as long as the text boxes are inside of the update panel, then you should not experience a full page post-back.
The above code thus works fine.
So, you need to post a minimal and re-producible example. In other words, create a fresh new test page, and with the minimal amount of markup and code, post an example that does not work.
